# How to set library_path in config for ImageMagick library which is installed in windows machine

Tags: php, windows, codeigniter, imagemagick, crop

I'm getting the following error while I try to crop an image using ImageMagick 
 library:

> Image processing failed. Please verify that your server supports the chosen protocol and that the path to your image library is correct

So the library is installed on my windows machine in program files(x 86) folder.

I have set the config like this:-

```
$config['image_library']  = 'ImageMagick';<br>
$config['library_path'] = 'C:\\ImageMagick\\Program Files (x86)\\';
```

I'm setting the `$config['library_path']` wrong and please note that the environment variable is as follows:-

path : -- C:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick

Comment: I have never had to set any paths after years of using Imagemagick on Windows. If you just use the exe file and allow it to add Imagemagick to the environment path all should be well. I suggest you uninstall what you have and try again

Comment: What version of Imagemagick did you install? IM 6 or IM 7? If IM 7, then it uses the command magick rather than convert. So this may cause problems.

Comment: Hey brian don’t you have to set library path for image crop through Imagemagick in codeigniter ?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @fmw42 - check your version of ImageMagick, and the command your image_lib.php is executing.

The `image_process_imagemagick()` function in my version of Codeigniter tries to execute *convert* command. In ImageMagick 7, this should be *magick*.

Ideally, update your CI version (I presume this is fixed in newer versions).

A quicker workaround, not to be advised, is to edit the $this->library_path var in `image_process_imagemagick()` method to read *magick*, instead of *convert*

```
if ( ! preg_match('/magick/i', $this->library_path))
    {
        $this->library_path = rtrim($this->library_path, '/').'/magick';
    }
```